# Why do my contour maps look different depending on data input?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm generating contour maps from a single maximum assuming a normal distribution. However for some reason my contour maps look different depending on the value of the single maximum. I have 3 examples of this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal


data_1=[8.58 ,8.584 ,8.569 ,8.538]
data_2=[119.614, 119.633, 119.697, 119.96 ]

#data_1=[8.601 ,8.605 ,8.607 ,8.624]
#data_2=[120.976 ,120.988 ,120.961, 120.988]

#data_1=[8.901, 8.907 ,8.902, 8.89 ]
#data_2= [121.547, 121.56,  121.547 ,121.514]
x_axis=np.linspace((min(data_1)-0.01),(max(data_1)+0.01),100)
y_axis=np.linspace((min(data_2)-0.01),(max(data_2)+0.01),100)
spread=[[2e-6, 1e-9], [1e-9, 2e-6]]
x,y=np.meshgrid(x_axis,y_axis)
pos=np.dstack((x,y))
pdf_sum=np.zeros_like(x)
for points in np.stack((data_1,data_2),axis=-1):
    pdf_sum+=(multivariate_normal(points,spread)).pdf(pos)
plt.contour(x,y,pdf_sum,levels=5,colors='black')

plt.show()
```

Comparison of the different datasets shows weird behaviors. The 2nd set is the best looking but I don't know what the black line in the first data set is, or why some of the contours in the 3rd data set only have 3 levels instead of 5.

Edit: It appear there is also a large huge circle around my contours as well, which I don't quite understand why (I believe the black lines are coming from this).

[image: First Data Set]

[image: Second Data Set]

[image: Third Data Set]

[image]

Comment: `levels=5` is asking matplotlib to guess 5 good-ish levels that span the _global_ spread of the data. Use a different specification for the contour levels if you want to take out the guesswork and/or focus on the high values instead of the full spread

Comment: @Brian61354270 this could explain why some contour levels are not exactly 5, but it doesn't explain the random black lines in the 1st dataset. Also how would I set levels for every single contour?

Comment: Those aren't random lines. Those are the spreads, they're just so large they run outside your plot ranges, and the contours of the bottom three overlapped so they got merged.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by @Brian61354270 and @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans. The reason the figures look different is because `matplotlib` is trying to find the best 5 levels to use objectively. The contour density is going to depend on your data but if you want to analyze your results it is helpful to look at the contour labels. I remade your figures with contour labels and with filled contours (easier for me to see quantitatively). Play around with the `levels` to see how that changes to better understand your data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

def get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread):
    x_axis=np.linspace((min(data_1)-0.01),(max(data_1)+0.01),100) # Try changing the resolution here
    y_axis=np.linspace((min(data_2)-0.01),(max(data_2)+0.01),100) # Try changing the resolution here
    
    x,y=np.meshgrid(x_axis,y_axis)
    pos=np.dstack((x,y))
    pdf_sum=np.zeros_like(x)
    for points in np.stack((data_1,data_2),axis=-1):
        pdf_sum+=(multivariate_normal(points,spread)).pdf(pos)
    return pdf_sum
    
# Decalre the Figure    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax3 = plt.subplot(133)

#
clevels = [0,.0000000001,.0001,1,10,100,1000]


# Subplot 1
#-------------------

data_1=[8.58 ,8.584 ,8.569 ,8.538]
data_2=[119.614, 119.633, 119.697, 119.96 ]
spread=[[2e-6, 1e-9], [1e-9, 2e-6]]

IM = ax1.contourf(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),alpha=.5,cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar_r)
CS = ax1.contour(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),levels=clevels,colors='black')
plt.colorbar(IM,ax=ax1)
plt.clabel(CS)

# Subplot 2
#-------------------

data_1=[8.601 ,8.605 ,8.607 ,8.624]
data_2=[120.976 ,120.988 ,120.961, 120.988]
spread=[[2e-6, 1e-9], [1e-9, 2e-6]]

IM = ax2.contourf(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),alpha=.5,cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar_r)
CS = ax2.contour(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),levels=clevels,colors='black')
plt.colorbar(IM,ax=ax2)
plt.clabel(CS)

# Subplot 3
#-------------------

data_1=[8.901, 8.907 ,8.902, 8.89 ]
data_2= [121.547, 121.56,  121.547 ,121.514]
spread=[[2e-6, 1e-9], [1e-9, 2e-6]]

IM = ax3.contourf(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),alpha=.5,cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar_r)
CS = ax3.contour(x,y,get_pdf(data_1,data_2,spread),levels=clevels,colors='black')
plt.colorbar(IM,ax=ax3)
plt.clabel(CS)



plt.show()
```

[image]